# Issue in creating jenkins jobs for different project types

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating a jenkins job using **create_job** method of **python-jenkins** package.for project type like "*freestyle*" and "*maven*" it is working fine.But for specific project type like "*multijob*" and "*flow*" it is getting failed and giving error like 
"Error Found .Possibly Authenticateion failed.Internal server Error(500)"

My yaml file 'yamlfile.yaml' contains the following:`- job:
    description: first project
    display-name: first
    name: first
    project-type: flow
    workspace: /root/devfolder/`

---

We have only this one yaml file passed to  command
**jenkins-jobs --conf  jenkins.ini yamlfile.yaml** to get the corresponding xml file

and the xml file that is returned to me from the command for project type "flow" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.BuildFlow>
<dsl/>
<buildNeedsWorkspace>false</buildNeedsWorkspace>
<actions/>
<description>first project&lt;!-- Managed by Jenkins Job Builder --&gt;       </description>
<keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
<displayName>9999</displayName>
<blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
<blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
<concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
<customWorkspace>/root/devfolder/</customWorkspace>
<canRoam>true</canRoam>
<properties/>
<scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
<publishers/>
<buildWrappers/>
```

---

The only change we are doing is that ,we are changing project type key value in yaml for differtent project type.

I am not sure of the xml specifications for creating jobs.i could not find even a document which can describe the same

.
Please help me with on creating jobs of different project types.